# Flex Application for PlayBook Text Input Variable

Tags: apache-flex, search, variables, mobile, input

I know this is probably a very simple question, but can someone please walk me through how to take what a user inputs into a s:TextInput and use that as a variable in a JSON data request?

Basically, I want to have a user enter a search term, like "math" and then have that placed into a variable so I can use it in a JSON request.

Something like public var q:String, except that my search box (and hence user input) is on another "view" of the application.

I've just started with Flex Mobile applications and I might be way out of my league.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The containing view should still be able to access teh child view's properties (and therefore controls); you just need the control(s) to have a unique ID, which then becomes a property name.  That said, I would consider the whole search feature to be self-contained, so it'd have its own controller (action script class for handling actions) wired up to the search button, adn have a reference to the view that it can extract the info from, etc.

Comment: I don't fully understand.  You think that the button should capture the user input and then pass it along to another script? What would be the advantage of doing so, and how would I go about doing it? Part of the problem is there's a disconnect in my mind between actionscript and the MXML.

Comment: ok, so when your app compiles, mxml becomes a class merged w/ its associated codefile and inline actionscript.  that class exposes a property for each control w/ an id that you've defined on it.  A well architected app, though, will also have regular classes taht handle most of hte business logic, and your views will just wire events to methods on those classes, which helps promote reuse and maintainability.  Look into the Model-View-Controller patterna nd Model-View-ViewModel pattern for some insight and explanation of the benefits.